# Why is my ship not shooting bullets?

Tags: python, pygame

I have made a game using Python and Pygame. My ship moves around but I am having trouble making it shoot bullets. I have defined a function called `shootBullets()` but it is not working. And now, if I press the space bar, my ship moves. It is only supposed to move when I press the left or right arrow keys. I want my ship to shoot bullets towards the bottom of the screen when I press the space bar. here is my code:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)
bright_blue = (0, 135, 255)
yellow = (255,242,0)
ship_body = (33, 117, 243)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))
pygame.display.set_caption("Battleship")
gameExit = False
background = pygame.image.load("Sky Background.png")
bulletImg = pygame.image.load("Bullet.png")
bulletY = 80

def shootBullets():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_SPACE:
            bulletY += 5
            screen.blit(bulletImg,(247,bulletY))        

pygame.key.set_repeat(50,50)

ship_points = [ [100, 50], [180, 95], [320, 95], [400, 50], [250, 35] ] 
x = 0
y = 0

while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameExit = True      

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: x = -5
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: x = 5

            for point in ship_points:
                point[0] += x

            for point in ship_points:
                if point[0] <= 0 or point[0] >= 500:
                    gameExit = True    

    shootBullets()

    screen.fill(black)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    ship = [
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, ship_body, ship_points),
            pygame.draw.polygon(screen, black, ship_points, 1)]

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: You are not checking whether space is pressed or not. Why should space shoot bullets then?

Comment: Your `point[0] += x` line runs when _any_ key is pressed. `x` can be carried over from previous loop iterations.

Answer (score 1):

In your main loop you are only checking for left and right, not for space. You check in the function `shootBullets` whether space is pressed, but that is too late, shootBullets will never be executes (actually it will get executed if the `for event in get()` loop is somehow exited but that is not what you want).

Instead do something like:

```
while not gameExit:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            gameExit = True      

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                move_left()
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
               move_right()
            if event.key == pygame.SPACE:
               shootBullet()
            [...]
```

Comment: Can you edit your code so that it is correctly aligned

Comment: @PyNEwbie Sorry, you are right. I guess you can also edit other answers to fix errors like that.

Comment: I was going to edit yours but I was not totally sure for the alignment for the last if statement.  I thought it was as you corrected it but . . .